# Google analytics referals with multiple sites on one domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have two sites, both on the same domain name. I.E.

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/blog
```

I have an analytics account set up for both which works well; I can see that traffic for the sites in their respective accounts.  However, I want to be able to track referrals from `www.example.com/blog` to`www.example.com`.  Although I know referrals are occurring, I can't seem to find any way to track them in analytics.  I think something needs to change with my analytics code, but I am not sure what to do.  Do I need to do something with the cookie domain?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to specify the cookie path. Try:

```
//Tracking Code Customizations Only
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID']);
_gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/blog/']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

See [Tracking a Single Subdirectory](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#singleSubDirectory)

Comment: I changed my analytics code to what you suggested, but I still don't see referrals listed in the www.example.com analytics account.  This seems to have fixed half the problem, I can see referrals from www.examle.com -> www.example.com/blog but I still don't see referrals from www.example.com/blog -> www.example.com.  Is it possible to get those listed as well?  Thanks for your response.